# Weird SQL join produces different results than splitting it up

Tags: mysql, sql

I am importing table data from one CMS to another. Therefore, I have the model with "pn_" prefix, which is the old one. The tables of the new one carry "avsn_" in front.

There are game variants, gallery images and gallery categories. The tables look like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `avsn_gallery_categories2variants` (
  `categoryId` int(255) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
  `gameVariantId` int(255) NULL,  
  PRIMARY KEY (`categoryId`,`gameVariantId`)  
);

CREATE TABLE `avsn_games_variant` (
        `psId`  int(255) NOT NULL ,
        `variantId`  int(255) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT , 
        `gameId`  int(255) NOT NULL ,
        `variantTitle`  varchar(1000) NOT NULL ,
        `consoleId`  int(255) NOT NULL ,    
        `specialGenreID`  int(255) NULL,
        `releaseDay`  int(2) NOT NULL ,
        `releaseMonth`  int(2) NOT NULL ,
        `releaseYear`  int(4) NOT NULL ,
        `isFreeware`  bit NOT NULL ,
        `isReleased`  bit NOT NULL ,
        `installationAdvices`  text NULL ,
        `gameAdvices`  text NULL ,
        `additionalInformation`  text NULL ,
        `cover`  varchar(1000) NOT NULL ,
        `publishingStatus`  int(1) NOT NULL ,
        `creatorId`  int(255) NOT NULL ,
        `lastModified`  date NOT NULL ,
        `creationDate`  date NOT NULL ,
        PRIMARY KEY (`variantId`)
    );
```

The old tables are these:

```
CREATE TABLE `pn_gallery_categories` (
  `gallid` int(3) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `gallname` varchar(80) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `gallimg` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `server` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `galloc` longtext NOT NULL,
  `description` text NOT NULL,
  `parent` int(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT '-1',
  `visible` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `template` varchar(25) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Default',
  `thumbwidth` int(2) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '120',
  `numcol` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `total` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `lastadd` date DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`gallid`),
  KEY `gallid` (`gallid`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=2166 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;
```

The table avsn_gallery_categories2variants is not imported properly. There is more than one combination of a specific category with a variant. This should not be possible due to the old model allowing just one combination. I think there is something wrong with the JOIN in the import:

```
INSERT INTO
    `avsn_gallery_categories2variants`
    (
        SELECT 
            variant.variantId AS `variantId`,
            gallid            AS `categoryId`
        FROM
            pn_gallery_categories
        JOIN
            avsn_games_variant variant ON gallimg = variant.cover
    );
```

What I did for verification:

1 Make sure that there really is just 1 category:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM avsn_gallery_categories WHERE categoryId = 1897;
+------------+----------+---------------+---------------+--------+----------------+
| categoryId | parentId | title         | folder        | userId | isUserCategory |
+------------+----------+---------------+---------------+--------+----------------+
|       1897 |      630 | Gray Matter 2 | G/GrayMatter2 |     -1 |                |
+------------+----------+---------------+---------------+--------+----------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

2 Make sure, that there is just one association by requesting it directly:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM avsn_gallery_categories2variants WHERE categoryId = 1897;
+------------+---------------+
| categoryId | gameVariantId |
+------------+---------------+
| 1897 | 365 |
| 1897 | 542 |
+------------+---------------+
2 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

Oops! 2 rows. Okay, now check the JOIN fields for both variants:

The category's cover:

```
mysql> SELECT gallimg FROM pn_gallery_categories WHERE gallid = 1897;
+-----------------+
| gallimg         |
+-----------------+
| graymatter2.png |
+-----------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

ID 365:

```
mysql> SELECT cover FROM avsn_games_variant WHERE variantId = 365;
+-----------+
| cover     |
+-----------+
| radau.jpg |
+-----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

ID 542:

```
mysql> SELECT cover FROM avsn_games_variant WHERE variantId = 542;
+-----------+
| cover     |
+-----------+
| tkkg5.jpg |
+-----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Errm. Yeah. None of them fits the category. What is going wrong? I am kind of desperate finding a solution. Mabye I wrote too much SQL and can't see issues anymore by having an import script of like 5,5k lines.

I appreciate any good answers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it should be :

```
INSERT INTO
    `avsn_gallery_categories2variants`
    (
        SELECT 
            gallid            AS `categoryId`,
            variant.variantId AS `variantId`
        FROM
            pn_gallery_categories
        JOIN
            avsn_games_variant variant ON gallimg = variant.cover
    );
```

Or better yet :

```
INSERT INTO
    `avsn_gallery_categories2variants`
    (`categoryId`, `variantId`)
    (
        SELECT 
            gallid,
            variant.variantId
        FROM
            pn_gallery_categories
        JOIN
            avsn_games_variant variant ON gallimg = variant.cover
    );
```

I get from [the official documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert.html) that if you do not explicitly declare target columns, the order of the columns in the inner select should match the order of the columns in the target table. I don't think aliasing the columns in the select part has any effect.

Comment: oh man.... I am such a fool. Thank you for that positive punch in my face :D That's it, thank you. It was so dumb of me :D